# show if a value is unique in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query.  In this query I want to make a column where I can show if the value in the column `Phone` is unique or not.  How to do this?

This is the query:

```
SELECT ID, Phone
FROM tbltest
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `COUNT()` here as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT ID, Phone,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Phone) = 1 THEN 'unique' END AS label
FROM tbltest
ORDER BY ID;
```

Here is a version which should work on earlier versions of MySQL:

```sql
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Phone,
       CASE WHEN t2.cnt = 1 THEN 'unique' END AS label
FROM tbltest t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Phone, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM tbltest
    GROUP BY Phone
) t2
    ON t2.Phone = t1.Phone;
```